# Upgraded output for powershell script

Tags: powershell, ip, report, hostname

I am trying to write script that will check servers hostnames.
Now I have:

Computers.txt

```
    192.168.10.10
    192.168.10.11
    192.168.10.12
```

and script:

```
    $servers = get-content "C:\Script\computers.txt"
Invoke-Command -Credential company\admin1 -ComputerName $computers -scriptblock {[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("ComputerName")} | out-file C:\Script\report_hostnames.txt
```

And I have report:

```
Computer1
Computer2
Computer3
```

Could you help me add IP adress to report, and error status, like this:

```
192.168.10.10 Computer1
192.168.10.11 Computer1
192.168.10.12 Computer Unavailable
```

I tried: foreach; try, catch and if, else but cannot understand how to use it in right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
get-content "C:\Script\computers.txt" | foreach {
  $Response = Invoke-Command -Credential company\admin1 -ComputerName $_ -scriptblock {[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("ComputerName")} 

  write-output "$_ $Response" | out-file C:\Script\report_hostnames.txt
}
```

Using an array inside the -ComputerName attribute and then piping the output forward to out-file doesn't give you a way to access the contents of -ComputerName attribute (at least that I know of). Breaking it up into a basic foreach does.

Comment: Thank you, it is really works. But now it asks password for every record.
Trying to set:
$username = "company\admin1"
$password = cat C:\temp\pass.txt | convertto-securestring
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
         -argumentlist $username, $password
But something wrong.

Comment: Thank you for help.

Comment: Thank you for help.
This is how it looks like now:
`
$mycredentials = Get-Credential

Get-Content "c:\Script\computers.txt" |
foreach {
$job = invoke-command -credential $mycredentials -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {hostname.exe}
  write-output "$_ $job" | out-file "C:\Script\report_hostnames.txt" -Append
}
`

Comment: Yup, you got it, nice!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use DNS to look up the host names. Example:

```
Get-Content "IPAddresses.txt" | ForEach-Object {
  $outputObject = [PSCustomObject] @{
    "IPAddress" = $_
    "HostName"  = $null
  }
  try {
    $outputObject.HostName = [Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($_).HostName
  }
  catch [Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException] {
    $outputObject.HostName = $_.Exception.InnerException.Message
  }
  $outputObject
}
```

Comment: Thank you for solution, but I cannot use DNS, cause I am going to use hostname information to clean up old DNS records.

Comment: We have a lot of static records, and I am not sure that is safe to set the current timestamp on all records.